# How do you get PBR materials in menu?

Tags: materials, node-editor, interface, add-on, settings

Mine has IFC Material immediately under settings in Materials instead. Is this an add-on? (Didn't see it there either.) From this video: https://youtu.be/9zkJC1LJycc?t=548 Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! I still don't have PBR materials even after clicking "Use Nodes" though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I should have looked more closely.  He doesn't seem to say so, but he's using the [pbr materials add-on](https://3d-wolf.com/products/materials/) that you can download and install from the mentioned URL.

- Go to [3d Wolf](https://3d-wolf.com/products/materials/) and click download.  That will download the file *PBR Materials.zip*
- Open Blender and use the Edit Menu to Edit preferences
- Go to the Add-Ons Tab and click *install*
- Use the file browser that pops up to find *PBR Materials.zip* in your downloads and install it.
- After a minute it will appear in add-ons.  Click the box to select it:

[image: PBR Materials in add-ons]

Once you've done that, the PBR Materials panel should show up in materials properties in your Blender *when you have an object selected*:

[image: PBR panel in materials properties]